# Why the warning for default arguments?

Tags: c++, c++17

Using ReSharper with C++17, and I enabled many of the warnings just to see what my project warns me about. I get this:

```
Declaring a parameter with a default argument is disallowed[fuchsia-default-arguments]
```

The code in question is the constructor:

```
class Point2D
{
public:
    explicit Point2D(double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0);
};
```

I'm wondering why default arguments would be considered bad/poor/worthy of a warning? Does anyone have any code examples proving this a viable warning?

[Here is the documentation.](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/fuchsia-default-arguments.html)

Comment: I don't know much about ReSharper but it appears you've enabled clang-tidy's fuschia-* family of checks. That project's coding conventions must frown upon the use of default arguments, that doesn't mean they're inappropriate in general.

Comment: @Praetorian, yah I'm just going to turn them off.  I was just curious for my own understanding, why a team would find this to be bad.  Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217635/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-this-warning-from-clang-tidy-fuchsia-default-arguments

Comment: I’m not endorsing this, but some folks think it’s better to write a set of overloaded functions than a single one with default arguments.

Comment: Recommend removing the c++17 tag as this behavior is not changed in that version of the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several odd corner cases when it comes to default arguments on function parameters.

Here is a presentation from CppCon 2017 detailing a lot of tricky behavior.  https://youtu.be/NeJ85q1qddQ

To summarize the main points:

- Redeclarations cause potentially confusing behavior
- The default arguments used in virtual function calls are not determined by the function called, but by the static type.
- Default arguments on function templates can potentially look ill-formed, but may compile as long as they are not instantiated.

Of course, for your case of a non-template constructor, they are fairly innocuous. It can’t be overridden or redeclared (although an out-of-line definition might cause you possible pain).